# My Raspberry Pi won't boot into Raspbian any more?

Tags: raspbian, boot

My Raspberry Pi was working fine last time I used it.  Now the boot sequence stops at this:

[image]

[Here is a larger version of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2F4p.jpg) (sorry, I couldn't get it any sharper).

What could the problem be and how can I fix this?

Comment: please show a more clear photo

Comment: That's as clear as I could get it. It's not perfect, but you can make out the text. This is a larger version of the image http://i.imgur.com/HDduTEk.jpg

Comment: there's a USB hub connected. What else? Have you tried booting it with nothing connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was do reinstall the operating system.